# Pandas: combine groupby-apply with join/merge

Tags: python, pandas

I often find myself doing a groupby-apply on a dataframe followed by merging the result with the original dataframe. Here's an example. Suppose `df` has columns A and B. I want to add another column whose value is the sum of column B over all rows with the same column A value as the current row. The following does the job but it is obviously sub-optimal

```
df.join(df.groupby('A')['B'].sum(), on='A', rsuffix='_sum')
```

Is it possible instead to keep the original index in groupby-sum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform`:

```
df['B_sum'] = df.groupby('A').B.transform('sum')
```

---

*Demo*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [1,1,2,2],
        'B': [1,2,3,4]
    })

df['B_sum'] = df.groupby('A').B.transform('sum')

df
#   A   B   B_sum
#0  1   1   3
#1  1   2   3
#2  2   3   7
#3  2   4   7
```